# How i can change numbers to chars?

Tags: java

i have a java code below,i need to get same result with characters instead of numbers.(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) => (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)  ,How i can change the code,thank you.

```
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    int len = numbers.length;
    int numberOfPer = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < len; l++) {
                    for (int m = 0; m < len; m++) {
                        for (int n = 0; n < len; n++) {
                            for (int o = 0; o < len; o++) {
                                if ((i != j) && (i != k) && (i != l)
                                        && (i != m) && (i != n) && (i != o)
                                        && (j != k) && (j != l) && (j != m)
                                        && (j != n) && (j != o) && (k != l)
                                        && (k != m) && (k != n) && (k != o)
                                        && (l != m) && (l != n) && (l != o)
                                        && (m != n) && (m != o) && n != o
                                        && (j - i != 1) && (k - j != 1)
                                        && (l - k != 1) && (m - l != 1)
                                        && (n - m != 1) && (o - n != 1)
                                        && (j - i != -1) && (k - j != -1)
                                        && (l - k != -1) && (m - l != -1)
                                        && (n - m != -1) && (o - n != -1)) {
                                    System.out.println(numbers[i] + ""
                                            + numbers[j] + "" + numbers[k]
                                            + "" + numbers[l] + ""
                                            + numbers[m] + "" + numbers[n]
                                            + "" + numbers[o]);
                                    numberOfPer++;

                                }
                            }
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
            System.out.println("Number of codes: " + numberOfPer);
```

Comment: Wow. I haven't ever seen 7 nested `for` loops until now. I guess you should think about your program design. You should also point out what you want to achieve with your code.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish we may be able to help you improve your code's efficiency.

Comment: I think 3 is the most nested loops I've ever seen, and that if statement at the end makes me squirm. If I did my basic calculation right this is like O(36N^6)! I would rethink my design if I was you

Comment: I think it is more important to describe what you are trying to do, rather than trying to fix this code. The code as it stands is unmaintainable.

Comment: Please tell us WHAT EXACTLY you want to achieve. Because if you want to have chars, why not simply try `char[] numbers =  new char[]{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' };`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
 (char) ('a' + i)
```

Comment: could you give me more details for how i do it please?

Comment: e.g. when you have 0 in numbers[l] in your example then (char)('a' + numbers[l]) is 'a' when numbers[1] is 2 then it is c - you might want to substrace 1 when you do not start by 0

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with inserting a char with ascii code: A is 65, so on...
Psudo code:

```
Read numbers: {1,2,3} //A,B,C
For each number, print out: 
//Like in C:
putch(numbers[] + 65); //putch outputs a character in ascii code. I dont know java much, but that should work.
```

Comment: Java uses Unicode/UTF-16 not ASCII. In C, you would very seldom use ASCII, either, but likely use Windows-1252 or similar or UTF-8. But, yes, in all of those 65 identifies 'A'.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
char[] letters = new char[ numbers.length ];
for( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i )
{
    if( 0 < numbers[i] && numbers[i] <= 26 )
       letters[i] = (char)( numbers[i] + 'a' - 1 ); // subtract 1 since you are using 1='a' not 0='a'
}
```